# Redirect single directory to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

1. I want to redirect directory `/api/` and everything after it to HTTPS. Everything else must redirect to HTTP if a visitor tries to visit something with HTTPS.
2. I'd like WordPress to ignore the `/api/` directory (and everything after it) from the current mod rewrite.

This is my current standard WordPress .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} YourFolderName 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/YourFolderName /$1 [R,L]
```

(Taken from [HERE](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/force-ssl-htaccess.html) for more info)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Good tip about the NC flag, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  For example, when I visit `mysite.com/API/`, it only redirects to `mysite.com`

Comment: Apache is case sensitive. /API/ and /api/ are not the same. You'd need to add another RewriteCon for that.

Comment: Also, put the https redirect lines ABOVE your standard Wordpress redirect lines.